# Cartoon where two brothers discover a secret passage at Stonehenge, and encounter spider-legged monsters that shoot ice beams

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I watched this cartoon around 15 years ago, and I'd guess it was from the '90s. I'm quite sure it wasn't part of a series.

I recall the following plot details:

- There were two brothers.
- They find a secret passage at Stonehenge by accident.
- The little brother is caught by monsters which have spider legs, and can shoot ice beams. The monsters charge the beams before shooting, like they're holding a ball above their head.
- The big brother saves the little brother with a legendary sword kind of thing.
- I'm not sure, but there might be a place like Atlantis too.

Answer (score 6):

I watched the Turkish dubbed version of the same cartoon as a kid around 2005. After losing the disc and not remembering much details, I tried to find its name for a long time and finally found it.

The original language of the cartoon is Italian with the name "Atlantide La città sommersa" and it is produced in 2001, see [the IMDB page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt21084824/). There is a high quality upload in Italian [here on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pf39SLOGU90&ab_channel=TheCartoonianArchive). There is also a low quality English version translated as "Atlantis: The Underwater City" [also on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGbra1Lz668&ab_channel=MollyJennings).

---

To verify your descriptions, here are some timestamps from the [first video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pf39SLOGU90&ab_channel=TheCartoonianArchive):

- **There were two brothers:** The beginning of the cartoon, starting from 0:30.
- **They find a secret passage at Stonehenge by accident:** 5:50
- **The little brother is caught by monsters which have spider legs, and can shoot ice beams. The monsters charge the beams before shooting, like they're holding a ball above their head:** Monster charging and shooting at 30:35, couldn't find the exact time where the brother is caught.
- **The big brother saves the little brother with a legendary sword kind of thing:** 25:45
- **I'm not sure, but there might be a place like Atlantis too:** The name of the movie is already Atlantis, or see 8:05.

Comment: Do you have a time hack for any of the specific incidents mentioned in the question? The monsters charging the beams before shooting would probably make this a slam dunk. Otherwise it's hard to see if your answer is correct without watching the whole video.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I have added the times of these events in the video

Comment: Looks like you nailed it! +1

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of close to that would be *[The Corsican Brothers by Alexandre Dumas: An Animated Classic](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0142193/)*.

[image: Cover image of The Corsican Brothers]

> A vendetta between two Corsican families is the background to Alexandre Dumas 's story of the strange bond between Siamese twin brothers, who are separated at birth.

It's probably not this one since I doubt anyone was watching it 15yrs ago...it's far older than that.

The henge can be first seen around 21 minutes in.

[image: Image of the wizards scheming in the henge]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Rather than require every reader to watch the movie, you should explain the details that match (and don't match) the question. Maybe include time codes for significant events to make it easier for people who do find the movie.